# pthread program results in segmentation fault

Tags: c, pthreads

I've been trying to create a chat program in C with threads but it hasn't been working, so I decided to play with threads for a bit first. I'm trying to run a thread that prints "hello world", but it gives me a segmentation fault. I haven't been able to find the root of the problem so I came here. heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <pthread.h>

void* test(void * arg) {
    printf("hello world\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t test;
    pthread_create(&test, NULL, (void *) test, NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

There's probably a stupid reason why it's not working so I hope you guys wont have too much trouble finding it!

Comment: The third argument of pthread_create refers to local variable not the function you inteded.

Comment: You need a `pthread_join` See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534498/c-posix-thread-basics for some fixes to very similar code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your start routine name and thread id name are the same so I think compiler gets confused when you pass &test. Your code works by changing the thread id name.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <pthread.h>

void* test(void * arg) {
    printf("hello world\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, (void *) test, NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the compiler's not getting confused at all, it's doing exactly what it was told to. The confusion is happening earlier in the development process :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
void* test(void * arg) { ... }

//        vvvv
pthread_t test;
pthread_create(&test, NULL, (void *) test, NULL);
//                                   ^^^^
```

That `pthread_t` variable is "hiding" the function name. In other words, you're calling some arbitrary uninitialised value as your function. That's unlikely to end well :-)

What you're doing is really no different to expecting the following program to output `7` (it won't):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int i = 7;
int main(void) {
    int i = 42;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

You could solve it simply by renaming your function to `testFn`, for example.